# Belkin wifi netcam cloud storage

Tags: network

If my net/router turns off with the belkin netcam will i still receive video if the motion sensor is activated? I was considering purchasing one, but if all that needs to be done is simply turning off the wireless router I really do not see the point. Any help is appreciate :)

Comment: this is a product question and not a InfoSec question - please contact a Belkin forum.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the place to ask, but it is a wifi camera and there is no DVR function attached to it, therefore if you do not have a wireless router or if the router/access point turns off then you will not receive the video stream.

NOTE: I do not own the product nor do am I affiliated with Belkin so my answer could *potentially* be wrong.